# Bounded waiting in Peterson's solution

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, system

Considering two processes:

Process 0

```
do{
flag[0] = TRUE;
turn = 1; 
while (flag[1] && turn == 1);
    critical section
flag[0] = FALSE;
remainder
}while(1)
```

Process 1

```
do{
flag[1] = TRUE;
turn = 0; 
while (flag[0] && turn == 0);
    critical section
flag[1] = FALSE;
remainder
}while(1)
```

Where `flag[]` and `turn` are shared variables.
Suppose process 0 starts executing first and it stops looping at `while`. Then process 1 goes and stops as well at `while`. Then process 0 resumes executing, while condition breaks and it executes its critical section. Fine. 
My question is how is bounded waiting guaranteed? In this scenario I can't seem to work it out:
Process 0 exits the critical section sets `flag[0] = FALSE;`  but then Process 1 does not resume executing rather Process 0 starts all over again, sets `flag[0] = TRUE;` and can reenter critical section code. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Process 0 exits the critical section sets flag[0] = FALSE; but then
>   Process 1 does not resume executing rather Process 0 starts all over
>   again, sets flag[0] = TRUE;

Yes you are right till here but when Process 0 starts all over again and tries to re-enter critical section , it will execute the following two statements again:

```
flag[0] = TRUE;
turn = 1;
```

so **turn** will be **1** and as we know Process 1 has not yet entered critical section due to which the **flag[1]** is still **true** and therefore the loop condition

```
 while (flag[1] && turn == 1);
```

will be **true**,**This means that process 0 will not be able to enter critical section twice.** This satisfies the condition of **Bounded Waiting.** Also whenever Process 1 will resume its execution the condition

```
while (flag[0] && turn == 0);
```

will become false as **turn is 1** and it will indeed enter critical section.